# ReactJS - Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag Error. When trying to include two <tr> tag

Tags: reactjs, html-table

Am working in the Reactjs application with mongoDB. Am getting data from MongoDB and displaying in the table. Due to the table row is too long. I want to split the table row into two lines.

So, for this am trying to include two `<tr>` tags but it giving me the error `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`.

I have written 3 separate component class for this requirement.

Please find my code below. ( Am using ReactJS 15.6.1 version )

```
class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
    this.state = { item: props.item };
    }

            render() {

            return (
            <table className="table table-bordered" style={{fontsize: '8'}}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Line Number</th>
                        <th>Product Code</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <DetailsList items={ this.state.item.order_items }  />
            </table>
        );   
    }
}

class DetailsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }
 render() {
       return (<tbody>{ this.props.items.map((item) => <DetailsItem key={ 
 item.line_id } item={ item } />) }
                  </tbody>);    
        }
}

class DetailsItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { item: props.item };
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td><input name="line_number" type="text"  
                     value={ this.state.item.line_number }  /> </td>
                <td><input name="product_code" type="text"
                     value={ this.state.item.product_code }  /></td>
                <td><input name="product_description" type="text"
                     value={ this.state.item.product_description } /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                Product Quantity <td>{ this.state.item.product_quantity } />
                                </td>
                Unit Price <td>{ this.state.item.unit_net_price }  /></td>
            </tr>

        );
    }
}
```

For Example am trying to like below snippet.

```
return(
        <tr>
            <td>.....</td>
            <td>.....</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>.....</td>
            <td>.....</td>
        </tr>
     )
```

I already wrapped my `<tbody>` tag with `props` data in my previous component.

```
 render() {
       return (<tbody>{ this.props.items.map((item) =>
       <DetailsItem key={ item.line_id } item={ item } />) }  </tbody>);    
        }
 }
```

If i use single `<tr>` tag instead of two, then its working fine. But i want to split this row into two.

[Please find the screenshot after adding `<div>` tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyZd8.png)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `JSX` does not allow unwrapped adjacent HTML elements. This is because `React` uses Javascript to create the DOM elements. So something like this:

```
return (
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <h1>World</h>
)
```

causes `React` to call `document.createElement()` twice, one for the `<h2>` and one for `<h1/>`, and this is not allowed.

If you really need to separate your `table rows` rather render them as an array. That is:

```
return([
    <tr>
        <td>.....</td>
        <td>.....</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>.....</td>
        <td>.....</td>
    </tr>
 ])
```

Please note though, that, this approach works for at least `React16`. Otherwise, I would suggest to simply wrap these separated `table rows` with a `div`. That is:

```
return(
 <div>
    <tr>
        <td>.....</td>
        <td>.....</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>.....</td>
        <td>.....</td>
    </tr>
 </div>
)
```

I would also like to point out that, this does not have to be a `div`. It could be other HTML elements, the point is to return one HTML element inside the `render()` of your component.

Comment: I tried with `<div>` tag but the table row was completely disturbed. Please find the attached screenshot of my output

Comment: Oh well, at least that is a styling issue. Also, it does not have to be a `div`, it could be anything, for as long as you are returning a single `html` element in the `render()`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using React 16+, you can return an array.

```
return [
  <tr>
      <td>.....</td>
      <td>.....</td>
  </tr>,
  <tr>
      <td>.....</td>
      <td>.....</td>
  </tr>
]
```

Comment: even he/she can, key props is still required.

Comment: Am using ReactJS 15.6.1 version. But i also tried with `return[ ]` approach its not working.

Comment: Yeah, you need 16+. If your project just started, I recommend you to upgrade to React 16.